# Proof of Identity for Lagrangians

Tags: multivariable-calculus, calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

My textbook states (in a derivation of the Euler-Lagrange equation) the following which I would like to understand:
\begin{equation*}
S[\bar{x}+\delta x] =\int_{t_a}^{t_b} L(\dot{x}+\delta \dot{x}, x+\delta x, t) dt =\int_{t_a}^{t_b}\left[L(\dot{x}, x, t)+\delta \dot{x} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}+\delta x \frac{\partial L}{\partial x}\right] d t\end{equation*}
How are the integrands equal to each other?
Using the definition of partial derivative, I can write the following for $\dot{x}$
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}} =\frac{L(\dot{x}+\delta \dot{x}, x, t)-L(\dot{x}, x, t)}{\delta \dot{x}}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    L(\dot{x}+\delta\dot{x}, x, t) =\delta \dot{x} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}+L(\dot{x}, x, t)
\end{equation*}
Similarly, for $x$:
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{\partial L}{\partial x}  =\frac{L(\dot{x}, x+\delta x, t)-L(\dot{x}, x, t)}{\delta x}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    L(\dot{x}, x+\delta{x}, t) =\delta x \frac{\partial L}{\partial x}+L(\dot{x}, x, t)
\end{equation*}
If I add the two expressions, I get:
\begin{equation*}
    \delta\dot{x}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}+\delta x \frac{\partial L}{\partial x}+2 L(\dot{x}, x, t)=L(\dot{x}, x+\delta x, t)+L(\dot{x}+\delta \dot{x}, x, t)
\end{equation*}
By Identification with the original statement:
\begin{equation*}
L(\dot{x}, x+\delta x, t)+L(\dot{x}+\delta \dot{x}, x, t)+L(\dot{x}, x, t)=L(\dot{x}+\delta \dot{x}, x+\delta x, t)
\end{equation*}
Why is this true, and generally how would you prove the statement yourself?
I feel like there is a basic fact of calculus that I am forgetting. Some help would be lovely.

Comment: They're not literally equal. They're equal when $\delta x$ is "small." The calculus identity you may be forgetting is that $df = \sum_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i} dx^i$.